# Admin наследуется от User, однако компилятор выдаёт ошибку C2504. "User: не определён базовый класс"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

C2504. "User: не определён базовый класс" - несмотря на то, что я подключил "#pragma once" и написал "#include "User.h"" в "Admin.h", а так же написал "class User" в начале.

```
/User.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "BankCard.h"
#include "product.h"
#include "Group.h"
#include "Admin.h"
using namespace std;

class BankCard;
class Group;
class Admin;

class User {
public:
    User(std::string name, int date_birthday, int age, std::string password);
    //void operator=(const User&user);
    static int Count;
    int GetDateRegistration() { return date_registration; };
    int GetDateBirthday() { return date_birthday; };
    int GetAge() { return age; };
    int GetCoinsCounter() { return coins_counter; };
    void SetName(std::string name) { this->name = name; };
    std::string GetName() { return name; };
    int GetCounterSoild() { return counter_soild; };
    int GetCounterSales() { return counter_sales; };
    void SetCounterSoild(int counter_soild) { this->counter_soild = counter_soild; };
    void SetCounterSales(int counter_sales) { this->counter_sales = counter_sales; };
    int GetExperience() { return experience; };
    void Create_Group(Group group, User user, Admin admin);
    int AccrualCoins();
    void Exchange(product prod);
    void BuyProduct(BankCard bank_card_user, product prod);
    void BuyCoins(BankCard bank_card_user);
    void SetAvailable(bool available) { this->available = available; };
    bool GetAvailable() { return available; }
private:
    int date_registration;
    int date_birthday;
    int age;
    std::string password;
    int coins_counter;
    std::string name;
    int id;
    int counter_soild;
    int counter_sales;
    int experience;
    bool available;
    bool check_create;
    vector <Group> groups;
};
```

Admin.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Group.h"
#include "product.h"
#include "User.h"
 
class User;
class Group;
class product;
using namespace std;

class Admin : public User
{
public:
    Admin(string name, int date_birthday, int age, string password, string status);
    void ConfigurationGroup(Group group);
    void DeleteAnyProduct(product prod, Group group);
    void BannedUser(User user);
private:
    std::string status;
};
```

Comment: А зачем у Вас циклическое включение заголовочных файлов? Возможно, из-за этого и ошибка.

Comment: Чтобы user в своих методах, мог принимать параметр Admin в виде аргумента.

Comment: При циклическом подключении заголовочных файлов, Вы получаете неопределенное поведение.

Comment: На сколько понимаю, попытка выстроить подобные зависимости обычно вызвана ошибкой проектирования.  Не утверждаю, что у Вас именно такая ситуация, но проверьте, а точно ли те функции в User, которые принимают Admin, должны находиться в User? Может есть смысл переместить из в Admin?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов  Не-а, убрав метод и циклическую зависимость - он введёт ту же самую историю

Comment: @Gisg... Прошу прощения, не понял? Какую историю?  И почему?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Удаляя метод и подключение "Admin.h" в "User.h" - я устранил циклическую зависимость, НО ошибка остается та же.

Comment: @Gisg, к сожалению, у меня нет майкрософтовского компилятора, возможно там есть какие-то отличия, о которых я не знаю. Проверил в Qt+MinGW. Убрал из User.h включение Admin.h и объявление функции Create_Group, после этого все собралось. К сожалению, Вы не предоставили минимально воспроизводимый пример, поэтому мне пришлось доопределить конструкторы классов User и Admin, удалить неопределенные функции из обоих классов, и сделать заглушку для класса Group. Возможно, это повлияло на результат